# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple while doing some calculation in a nested list

Tags: python

I am trying to do some calculation in nested lists

The example is `[['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]`, and I want to see the output like:
`[[3.0,'Amy'],[3.5,'Jack']]`(3.0 is mean of 2,3,4 and 3.5 is mean of 3,4)

**My code:**

```
def compute_mean_pc():
    students_pclist=[['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]
    mean_pc=[[[countMean(students_pclist[element][1:])]for element in enumerate(students_pclist)]+[element[0]]for element in students_pclist]
    print(mean_pc)


def countMean(array):
    count=0
    sumup=0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i]!=None:
            count+=1
            sumup+=array[i]
    mean=sumup/count
    return mean

compute_mean_pc()
```

the second part, countMean(array) works well, but for the first part,in this line

```
mean_pc=[[[countMean(students_pclist[element][1:])]for element in enumerate(students_pclist)]+[element[0]]for element in students_pclist]
```

Python returns a type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong part in your code is `for element in enumerate(students_pclist)` inside your list comprehension: [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple on each iteration loop. So you should have written  something like `for element,i in enumerate(students_pclist)`.
It fixes your error, but it does not give you the expected answer.

Here is a suggestion of complete fix, based on your code:

```
myListOfLists = [['Amy',2,3,4], ['Jack',3,4,None]]

def compute_mean_pc():
    students_pclist=[['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]
    mean_pc=[ [countMean(student[1:])] +[student[0]] for student in students_pclist]
    print(mean_pc)


def countMean(array):
    count=0
    sumup=0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i]!=None:
            count+=1
            sumup+=array[i]
    mean=sumup/count
    return mean

compute_mean_pc()
#  [[3.0, 'Amy'], [3.5, 'Jack']]
```

And finally I suggest you a code which is more efficient and still readable, using a good old-fashioned for loop:

```
myList = [['Amy',2,3,4], ['Jack',3,4,None]]

def compute_mean_pc(myList):
    result = []
    for name, *values in myList:            # iterate over each sub-list getting name and next values
        values = list(filter(None,values))             # Remove any 'None' from the values 
        result.append([name, sum(values)/len(values)]) # Append a list [name,mean(values)] to the result list
    return result

result = compute_mean_pc(myList)

print(result) # [['Amy', 3.0], ['Jack', 3.5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help^_^

Answer (score 1):

`for element in enumerate(students_pclist)` will assign a tuple `(index, element_of_students_pclist)` to `element`.

What you want is:

```
[[countMean(element[1:]), element[0]] for element in students_pclist]
```

Answer (score 1):

You had problems with correctly using index returned by the `enumerate`. I just slightly modified your code with the correct way of using `enumerate`

```
def compute_mean_pc():
    students_pclist=[['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]
    mean_pc=[[ countMean(students_pclist[i][1:]) ] + [element[0]] for i, element in enumerate(students_pclist)]
    print(mean_pc)
```

**Output**

```
[[3.0, 'Amy'], [3.5, 'Jack']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should do what you need:

```
a = [['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]

def computeMean(array):
    valid = [i for i in array[1:] if i]
    return [sum(valid)/len(valid)]

result = [computeMean(sub) + sub[:1] for sub in a]
result
#[[3.0, 'Amy'], [3.5, 'Jack']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to count mean:

```
def compute_mean_pc():
    students_pclist=[['Amy',2,3,4],['Jack',3,4,None]]
    mean_pc=[ [student[0], count_mean(student)]  for student in students_pclist]
    print(mean_pc)


def count_mean(array):
    grades = [el for el in array if isinstance(el, int)]
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)

compute_mean_pc()
```